# EvaluateJsonPath unable to return a scalar

Tags: json, apache-nifi, jsonpath

I'm trying to extract a value from JSON to a **flowfile-attribute**. When I run the EvaluateJsonPath processor I get an error stating

`"Unable to get a scalar value for expression $..fields.storyBoard.stringValue`.

**Input JSON looks like this:**

```
{
  "name" : "projects/fakedims-0000/databases/(default)/documents/device/0000",
  "fields" : {
    "reportKey" : {
      "stringValue" : "abc123"
    },
    "dateOccured" : {
      "timestampValue" : "2018-10-14T04:00:00Z"
    },
    "storyBoard" : {
      "stringValue" : "https://path/to/media"
    },
    "new" : {
      "integerValue" : "25"
    },
    "name" : {
      "stringValue" : "device one"
    },
    "location" : {
      "geoPointValue" : {
        "latitude" : -78.413751,
        "longitude" : 38.156487
      }
    }
  },
  "createTime" : "2018-10-19T00:02:26.209335Z",
  "updateTime" : "2018-10-19T22:22:24.382136Z"
}
```

The JSONPath expression is `$..fields.storyBoard.stringValue`

What I think is happening is that the processor is returning `["https://path/to/media"]` rather than just the string.

This is what I get if a evaluate to flowfile-content rather than an attribute. Why? What can I do to fix it?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Change the **Return Type property** value to **json** in `EvaluateJsonPath` processor, if you are extracting as flowfile-attribute

**Return Type property description:**

> Indicates the desired return type of the JSON Path expressions.
>   Selecting '**auto-detect**' will set the return type to '**json**' for a
>   Destination of '**flowfile-content**', and '**scalar**' for a Destination of
>   '**flowfile-attribute**'.

[image]
As you are trying to extract nested key not the key on the root level(ex:name,createTime..), that's the reason why we need to configure the Return Type as **Json** not as **scalar**.

In Addition you can use **[FlattenJson](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.5.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.FlattenJson/index.html) processor(seperator '_')** to flatten-out all nested json then use `Return Type as auto detect` in **EvaluateJsonPath** processor.

**EvaluateJsonConfigs:**
[image]

**Output:**
We are going to have attribute value without enclosing in an array
[image]